# How to display the 4th level of a menu using the Menu Block module?

Tags: 7, blocks

I use the [Menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module for a menu block that should display the 3rd and 4th levels of my main menu. It works great for the 3rd level of my menu, but for some reason I can't get it to display the 4th level of my menu as well. Does anyone know why that might be or how to fix that?

I have gone through most of the code in the menu block module, and everything I have found says that the 4th level is being rendered correctly, but it doesn't exist in the output code for some reason.